# Unreal Engine 4 blueprints how to disable ESC key?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I've been trying to figure out how to disable ESC or any other key in UE4 blueprints or C++, doesn't matter for me.

Do someone know how to disable ESC key in Blueprints or C++?
Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if it is bound to ESC in the input setting of the project setting on the blue print.
2. In the C++ project, search for Key=Esc with ctrl+shift+f. Clear the value of the setting directly, or unbind it to the c++ base of the actor file you want to control.